# Highlighting specific text in a web element

Tags: jquery

I need to apply a color to html  element, but only on a specific portion of the content.

Currently i mark each  with a class called matchedOn, and use the following Jquery to perform the neccessary colouring:

```
$('.matchedOn:contains("' + matchedItem + '")').css({ "color": "#008000", "background-color": "#FFFF00" });
```

matchedItem is a variable from an Ajax feed. Ok, so this work for the complete entry, so if the displayed text in the `<dd>` is `<dd>Hello there this is a test string</dd>` and in the example above the matchedItem is `'this is'`, how can i only assign the color attributes to just `'this is'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All style treatments need to be wrapped in a tag, so wrap a `<span class='highlight'>` around this text and add a `highlight` declaration in your stylesheet.

After finding the element with jQuery, you'll need to do a replace of the text in the `.html()` within the element to wrap the span around the text.

```
var match = $('.matchedOn:contains("' + matchedItem + '")')
$(match).html($(match).html().replace(matchedItem,"<span class='highlight'>"+matchedItem+"</span>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a JQuery plugin for this located here: [JavaScript text higlighting jQuery plugin](http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html)

You could write your own method for wrapping the text but i'm sure this will be a faster solution.

Comment: Thanks Jamie, but i went with Diodeus approach.